# html element press button

Tags: c#, winforms, html

I am trying to use the element ID of a button on a webpage to press the button but I don't know which values I am supposed to use to press the button.

```
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ucContent_cntrlRegister_btnRegister").SetAttribute("submit", "Sign Up");
```

that's what I have so far.

In the end I am trying to just press the button.

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically click a button?

Comment: basically but i want it to press a button on a webpage

Comment: Your code there suggests a different intention to your question. Are you trying to set an attribute? Or are you trying to click a button? Give us a bit more context to help understand.

Comment: I am trying to just press the button

Comment: Why? Maybe register a startup script and get your javascript to do whatever it is you  want to do client-side. Why are you trying to press the button first? Depending on your answer to that, pressing the button programmatically like this might not be the best way.

Comment: Wait there - why is winforms tagged? I'm confused with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ucContent_cntrlRegister_btnRegister").PerformClick();
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to have a .PerformClick(); It has a .Click(); but that requires me to have it on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: If that's not working have you tried webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ucContent_cntrlRegister_btnRegister").InvokeMember("click");

Comment: when i type .PerformClick(); after that it tells me this.

'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement' does not contain a definition for 'PerformClick' and no extension method 'PerformClick' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)